# Edge App in IE Mode - Hide Persistent Address Bar

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge, user-experience, ie8-compatibility-mode

I can't remove the address bar by installing the site as an app in the Edge browser.
I am using Win10 / Microsoft Edge in IE mode, the source is non-secure HTTP intranet.
I tried with edge://flags -> "Insecure origins treated as secure" to avoid unsafe warnings, but the top bar remains ..
Looking up, it might be due to changes to the address while opening and logging in.
Any suggestions about how to remove this persistent address bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't hide address bar in Edge app. The only way you can hide the address bar is using **kiosk mode**. If you can use this as workaround, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-configure-kiosk-mode) for more information about how to use kiosk mode.

The simplest way to use kiosk mode in Edge is using command-line options. For example, if you want to run Edge in kiosk mode with IE mode, you can right click on Edge shortcut, choosing **Properties**, adding `--kiosk www.yoursite.com --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen --ie-mode-force` at the end of **Target**, clicking **Apply** and **OK**. Please note that there's a space between the Edge path and the command-line options.

Next time when you double click to run Edge, it will launch in IE mode and kiosk mode with the specific url, it won't show the address bar.

[image]